# How to add URL handler for static html page in app.yaml running along Angular aplication

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

I'm trying to setup a static html page that will be shown once user has unsubscribed from mailing list. This file should be in the same Google App Engine as my main Angular 7 app. But when visiting URL `https://MYURL/unsubscribe` I get 404 error. How do I need to configure my app.yaml in order to get this kind of functionality working?

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

service: XXX

handlers:
  # handler for static unsubscribe page
  - url: /unsubscribe\.html
    static_files: unsubscribe.html
    upload: unsubscribe.html

  - url: /
    secure: always
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/.*
  - url: /(.*\.js)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/.*\.js
  - url: /(.*\.css)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    static_files: dist/\1
    mime_type: text/css
    upload: dist/.*\.css
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/.*

skip_files:
  - ^(?!dist)
  - ^(?!unsubscribe.html)
```

I expect to see the content of my unsubscribe.html file when I go to `https://MYURL/unsubscribe`, but instead I get error saying `Error: Not Found
The requested URL /unsubscribe.html was not found on this server.`

## UPDATE

Finally fixed it by combining last two line of my `app.yaml`file like so:

```
skip_files:
  - ^(?!dist|unsubscribe.html)
```

Now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.json` to configure your HTML file as asset:

```
{
   "assets": [
       "src/unsubscribe.html",
   ],
}
```

The above file treated same as other assets (images and stylesheets) which are accessible directly.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work like that. Would I need to change my app.yaml file too?

Comment: I do not think so. Maybe recompile?